# DJI "Video Stream Decoding Sample" : MediaCodec configured with null Surface issue

Tags: android, video, surfaceview, android-mediacodec, dji-sdk

I'm working on an Android mobile app oriented to the real time augmented visualization of a drone's camera view (specifically I'm working on a DJI Phantom 3 Professional with relative SDK). 
In order to study how to replace the camera stream in my AR framework with an external video stream, I'm trying the DJI demo "Video Stream Decoding Sample" (https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/sample-code/index.html).

In particular, I'm trying to get the raw video data coming from the MediaCodec just by setting the Surface parameter to null in the configure() method. So, I don't need to let MediaCodec to render the video stream, but I'd like to redirect every single output YUV frame using onYuvDataReceived()method. 
So I changed in MainActivity.java the following two code lines:

```
@Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

                DJIVideoStreamDecoder.getInstance().setYuvDataListener(MainActivity.this);
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

                DJIVideoStreamDecoder.getInstance().changeSurface(null);
            }
```

Now my problem is that, while in the first case (with Surface set into the MediaCodec) I can count an average frame rate of 30 frames per second, in this case (with Surface set to null) the average frame rate is about 15-16 decoded frames per second (and this could impact strongly the quality of the video rendering!). In particular, through debug, I observed that the problem was in the following section:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < CODEC_DEQUEUE_INPUT_QUEUE_RETRY && inIndex < 0; i ++) {
        //Log.i(TAGa,"FILE: DJIVideoStreamDecoder.java; CLASS: DJIVideoStreamDecoder; METODO: decodeFrame() -- 5");    //DEBUG
        try {
            Log.i(TAGa,"FILE: DJIVideoStreamDecoder.java; CLASS: DJIVideoStreamDecoder; METODO: decodeFrame() -- 6");    //DEBUG

            inIndex = codec.dequeueInputBuffer(0);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.i(TAGa,"FILE: DJIVideoStreamDecoder.java; CLASS: DJIVideoStreamDecoder; METODO: decodeFrame() -- 7");    //DEBUG

            logd(TAGa, "decodeFrame: dequeue input: " + e);
            codec.stop();
            codec.reset();
            initCodec();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

> log file:
>   02-05 21:42:58.112 I/DJIVideoStreamDecoder(27992): FILE: DJIVideoStreamDecoder.java; CLASS: DJIVideoStreamDecoder; METODO: decodeFrame() -- 1
>   02-05 21:42:58.112 I/DJIVideoStreamDecoder(27992): FILE: DJIVideoStreamDecoder.java; CLASS: DJIVideoStreamDecoder; METODO: decodeFrame() -- 6
>   02-05 21:42:58.112 I/DJIVideoStreamDecoder(27992): FILE: DJIVideoStreamDecoder.java; CLASS: DJIVideoStreamDecoder; METODO: decodeFrame() -- 6
>   02-05 21:42:58.112 I/DJIVideoStreamDecoder(27992): FILE: DJIVideoStreamDecoder.java; CLASS: DJIVideoStreamDecoder; METODO: decodeFrame() -- 6
>   02-05 21:42:58.112 I/DJIVideoStreamDecoder(27992): FILE: DJIVideoStreamDecoder.java; CLASS: DJIVideoStreamDecoder; METODO: decodeFrame() -- 6
>   02-05 21:42:58.112 I/DJIVideoStreamDecoder(27992): FILE: DJIVideoStreamDecoder.java; CLASS: DJIVideoStreamDecoder; METODO: decodeFrame() -- 6
>   02-05 21:42:58.112 I/DJIVideoStreamDecoder(27992): FILE: DJIVideoStreamDecoder.java; CLASS: DJIVideoStreamDecoder; METODO: decodeFrame() -- 6
>   02-05 21:42:58.112 I/DJIVideoStreamDecoder(27992): FILE: DJIVideoStreamDecoder.java; CLASS: DJIVideoStreamDecoder; METODO: decodeFrame() -- 6
>   02-05 21:42:58.112 I/DJIVideoStreamDecoder(27992): FILE: DJIVideoStreamDecoder.java; CLASS: DJIVideoStreamDecoder; METODO: decodeFrame() -- 6
>   02-05 21:42:58.112 I/DJIVideoStreamDecoder(27992): FILE: DJIVideoStreamDecoder.java; CLASS: DJIVideoStreamDecoder; METODO: decodeFrame() -- 6
>   02-05 21:42:58.112 I/DJIVideoStreamDecoder(27992): FILE: DJIVideoStreamDecoder.java; CLASS: DJIVideoStreamDecoder; METODO: decodeFrame() -- 6
>   02-05 21:42:58.112 I/DJIVideoStreamDecoder(27992): FILE: DJIVideoStreamDecoder.java; CLASS: DJIVideoStreamDecoder; METODO: decodeFrame() -- 6
>   02-05 21:42:58.112 I/DJIVideoStreamDecoder(27992): FILE: DJIVideoStreamDecoder.java; CLASS: DJIVideoStreamDecoder; METODO: decodeFrame() -- 6
>   02-05 21:42:58.112 I/DJIVideoStreamDecoder(27992): FILE: DJIVideoStreamDecoder.java; CLASS: DJIVideoStreamDecoder; METODO: decodeFrame() -- 6
>   02-05 21:42:58.122 I/DJIVideoStreamDecoder(27992): FILE: DJIVideoStreamDecoder.java; CLASS: DJIVideoStreamDecoder; METODO: decodeFrame() -- 6
>   02-05 21:42:58.122 I/DJIVideoStreamDecoder(27992): FILE: DJIVideoStreamDecoder.java; CLASS: DJIVideoStreamDecoder; METODO: decodeFrame() -- 6
>   02-05 21:42:58.122 I/DJIVideoStreamDecoder(27992): FILE: DJIVideoStreamDecoder.java; CLASS: DJIVideoStreamDecoder; METODO: decodeFrame() -- 6
>   02-05 21:42:58.122 I/DJIVideoStreamDecoder(27992): FILE: DJIVideoStreamDecoder.java; CLASS: DJIVideoStreamDecoder; METODO: decodeFrame() -- 6
>   02-05 21:42:58.122 I/DJIVideoStreamDecoder(27992): FILE: DJIVideoStreamDecoder.java; CLASS: DJIVideoStreamDecoder; METODO: decodeFrame() -- 6
>   02-05 21:42:58.122 I/DJIVideoStreamDecoder(27992): FILE: DJIVideoStreamDecoder.java; CLASS: DJIVideoStreamDecoder; METODO: decodeFrame() -- 6
>   02-05 21:42:58.122 I/DJIVideoStreamDecoder(27992): FILE: DJIVideoStreamDecoder.java; CLASS: DJIVideoStreamDecoder; METODO: decodeFrame() -- 6

As the log file shows, often dequeueInputBuffer() returns a negative inIndex value and some frames can't be inputted into the codec, because is not available an input buffer: this causes that only about a half of the frames will be correctly decoded.
I observe this issue only in the case in which surface is null ! What's wrong? Please give me some advice about this.

Answer (score 0):

When `dequeueInputBuffer` returns negative "indices," those values aren't actually meant to be interpreted as indices but instead as metadata. See the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html#dequeueOutputBuffer(android.media.MediaCodec.BufferInfo,%20long)) for `dequeueInputBuffer` and check out those INFO* constants (e.g. MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER, MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED, etc.). The top part of the page of documentation has some partial sample code on how to handle those.